Why are relative and absolute classes not working with NativeWind in Expo React Native?
I'm using NativeWind for Tailwind CSS in my Expo React Native project. However, I’m having issues with the relative and absolute positioning classes. They don’t seem to be working as expected.
import React from "react";
import { View, Image, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";


const IntroScreen = ({ navigation }: any) => {
return (
>     <View className="relative min-h-screen">
>       <Image
source={require("../../assets/welcome-page.png")}
className="w-full h-full"
>       />
>       <View className="absolute bottom-14 left-0 right-0 items-center">
>         <TouchableOpacity
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}
>         >
>           <Text className="text-white text-2xl font-semibold">Commencer {'>'} </Text>
>         </TouchableOpacity>
>       </View>
>     </View>
>   );
> };

export default IntroScreen;


Verified that NativeWind is correctly installed and configured.
Checked that Tailwind CSS classes are applied in other parts of the app.


Can you format your code properly? And please add your config files
